# ¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de un CheckBox para usarlo en un If?

Tags: android, booleano

Estoy intentando modificar el precio de un artículo pero este siempre me toma el valor true, 
¿cómo puedo hacer que vea si el usuario lo seleccionó? 
Este es mi código:

```
private int calculatePrice() {
    int price = 5;
    CheckBox whippedCreamBox   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_box);
    boolean haswhippedCreamBox = whippedCreamBox.isChecked();

    if (haswhippedCreamBox = true) {
       Log.v("main Activity", "false");
    } else {
        price = price + 2;
    }
    return quantity * price;
}
```

Comment: .... Espero que no sea esto, pero cambia tu if por `(haswhippedCreamBox == true)` dónde utilizas el `==` en lugar del `=` que te está ASIGNANDO el valor......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me da la sensacion que es debido a que en el IF estas asignando el valor true en vez de comparar. Tienes que usar la doble igualdad '==' para comparar.

Sería así:

```
if (haswhippedCreamBox == true) {
   Log.v("main Activity", "false");
} else {
    price = price + 2;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya funciona. Dos cosas te quería decir, soy nuevo y no consigo formatear mi código, ¿cómo se hace? y otra, cómo se mandan mensajes entre usuarios

Comment: Si te funciona acepta la respuesta :D. Respecto a formatear el código simplemente tiene que estar tabulado, hay una previsualización según escribes el mensaje, úsalo para ver como te va quedando. Por ultimo el tema de mensajes entre usuarios no tengo ni idea.

Comment: @Maxapp no existen un sistema de mensajes pero tenemos un chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol Para formatear tu código añade 4 espacios delante.